# Can I get a ActiveRecord::Connection instance from a ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid exception?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm performing a complex data import task, using *multiple* PostgreSQL database connections. Under certain conditions I need to perform a rollback on a *specific* database connection if I encounter a `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid` exception.

I cannot seem to get the `ActiveRecord::Connection` instance from that exception. What I can get is a `PG::Connection` instance from `exception.cause.connection`. Unfortunately I need the ActiveRecord instance to properly perform the rollback and keep the internal AR data structures in sync with the database. At the very least I need the name of the last savepoint, if any, to perform a manual rollback.

How can I get a `ActiveRecord::Connection` instance from a `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid` exception?

Comment: Are you using multiple clients or how are you distinguishing between the connections via the client(s)?

Comment: Just one client, but multiple connections on the model classes, i.e. `MyModel.establish_connection` and `MyModel.remove_connection`

Answer (score 0):

In case someone needs this, I'm posting my solution here.

In essence I'm just brute-forcing it by searching all connections from all pools and checking if the low-level connection matches my connection.

```
def ar_connection_from_pg_connection(pg_conn)
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection_handler.connection_pools.each do |pool|
    conn = pool.connections.find { |ar| ar.raw_connection == pg_conn }
    return conn if conn
  end
  nil
end
```